# How can I measure the dispersion of a discrete time system?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, computational-mathematics

I have a discrete time system: x[n+1]=A*x[n]+B[n], with B[n] as an excitation signal. How can I measure the dispersion of this system?
I guess this is related to some property of A, which depicts the system.

Comment: Your problem is well stated but, generally, problems with no work shown are frowned upon.

Comment: Lyapunov exponents?

Comment: Could you define the dispersion of a linear system here? What is random here? Input signal or/and initial state?

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for your reply first. The dispersion here is related to frequency. Suppose we have B(t) as an excitation signal with a wide frequency bandwidth, if a system is dispersive, the output sequence will distort when time evolves, this is because the signal components with different frequencies will have different velocities. The concept of dispersion is common in optics and detail information can be found in Wiki as https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics). Hope for your answer!